# Detect if re-connection has taken place in redis websocket on client side

Tags: django, websocket, redis, client-side

I am quite new to `django-websocket-redis` and as normal I am facing some problems.

I have established a communication from the client to the server and vice versa [using Websockets for Redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

I would like to detect when a client is `reconnected` or `disconnected` from the server (meaning when the connection is closed and/or opened again), so that I implement a mechanism where clients are responsible for asking "what did I miss" when they reconnect, and then query the data that they missed.

Currently my client code is like this [(fiddle here)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vzpLw6Ls/1/). 
I can detect when the connections is established for the first time, but not when websocket connection is broken and reconnected.

Any ideas on how can i do that ?

Comment: If something is not clear enough please ask

Comment: You can use the flag which you set once the connection is disconnected. And while reconnecting you can check the flag and identify if the connection was broken or reconnected.

Comment: What you proposed makes sense (of course), the thing is that I am not getting an "alarm" when the server is disconnected.Here is a screenshot to make things easier http://prntscr.com/b3jpkv

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. That really helped in understanding your problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the function name which you have set it should not be `on_connecting()` instead it should be only the name of the function `on_connecting`.

Below is the code, replace your code with below one and check if that works.

```
var ws4redis = WS4Redis({
    uri: '{{ WEBSOCKET_URI }}foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast&echo',
    receive_message: receiveMessage,
    connecting: on_connecting,
    connected: on_connected,
    error: on_error,
    disconnected: on_disconnected,
    close: on_close,
    open: on_open,
});
```

When you write `on_connecting()` the functions are getting called when the WS4redis is been initialized that's why you see the console log for all the events

Comment: @Paschalidis : Let me know if above solution works. Boz I am not able to actually run and verify.

Comment: I used to have the functions without parenthesis but then none of the functions were triggered. Weird right ?

Comment: @PaschalidisChristos: When you put brackets it is function call and when you just use the function name you assign the function which will be called once the event occurs. In your case the diconnected event.

Comment: Things worked out eventually. Thanks for the quick response @Amar .